# Make VBA automatically accept opening writeprotected files

Tags: vba, excel

I have a chunck of VBA code, which opens 2 files, copy the content in each, and paste that into a third file.
The problem is, that the two files (lets say "alm" and "fiber") often are used by other users, thus when i use `Set alm = Workbooks.Open(alm_path)` I get an error, since Excel cannot open it. I assume it is due to the file being opened by another user, and I then have to open it as write protected. Is there any smart way to do so? I am fairly new to VBA code

Comment: What have you researched / tried so far? What is the actual error you receive, and what makes you 'assume' it's because the file is already open?

Comment: How do you plan on opening it write protected if another user has it open?  Set the  `ReadOnly` parameter to True when you Open File 1 and File 2.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments you can open the workbook as ReadOnly, an example below:

```
Dim alm As Workbook
Set alm = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=alm_path, ReadOnly:=True)
```